# How to remove a line in Http header in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx in front of apache servers as a load balancer and to log access logs. To log some variables from web services to the nginx log, the services are writing to Http header which gets extracted by nginx. The problem is that these variables are rather internal info which I want to remove before passing back to the client. Is there an easy of removing specific http header line(s) in nginx?

Comment: Does http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header work for requests or is it just responses?

Comment: Good to know. Let me try.

Comment: @Danack, it worked. I was interested in response. Would you post your comment as an answer below? I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide a client request header with a Nginx reverse proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644744/hide-a-client-request-header-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which headers are passed from a proxied server to the client that made the request can be controlled with the config entries for [proxy_hide_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header) and [proxy_pass_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_header).

The 'pass' one forces headers that are normally removed to be shown to the client, and the hide one forces headers that are normally shown to be removed.

This allows you to remove or hide headers that you don't want to be shown to the end user.