# How to remove host header

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I want to remove Host header at ingress controller before sending the request to backend service. Will appreciate your insight.

My backend service is NOT expecting any Host header.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform is working on richer routing and transforms with HTTP(s) Load Balancer, used by Kubernetes Engine Ingress. No ETA is available.

In the meantime, you can use a proxy service in front of the application. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39750507/9019216) on how to remove a header with nginx.