# Remove all headers (except User-Agent) before proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

How do I tell nginx to remove all headers except User-Agent from a request before passing it to my proxy_pass location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide a client request header with a Nginx reverse proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644744/hide-a-client-request-header-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy-server)

Comment: @IvanShatsky No, unless it works with wildcard

Comment: If you want to use wildcards, you can try [`more_clear_input_headers`](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_clear_input_headers) directive from ['headers-more-nginx-module'](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) (to use that module you'll need to [build nginx from sources](http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html)). Or you can use an [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/) (or [lua-ngx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module)) and make use of [`ngx.req.clear_header`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqclear_header) API call.