# Nginx: Hide server signature

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-config

I have read a lot of questions on StackOverflow. For many people they were helpful, but for me not.

I need to hide the server name, or at least change it.

I wrote a **docker** file, to download a dynamic module and inject it into the configuration in the next step.

```
ARG VERSION=alpine
FROM nginx:${VERSION} as builder

ENV MORE_HEADERS_VERSION=0.34
ENV MORE_HEADERS_GITREPO=openresty/headers-more-nginx-module

RUN wget "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz" -O nginx.tar.gz && \
    wget "https://github.com/${MORE_HEADERS_GITREPO}/archive/v${MORE_HEADERS_VERSION}.tar.gz" -O extra_module.tar.gz

RUN  apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gcc \
    libc-dev \
    make \
    openssl-dev \
    pcre-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    linux-headers \
    libxslt-dev \
    gd-dev \
    geoip-dev \
    perl-dev \
    libedit-dev \
    mercurial \
    bash \
    alpine-sdk \
    findutils

SHELL ["/bin/ash", "-eo", "pipefail", "-c"]

RUN rm -rf /usr/src/nginx /usr/src/extra_module && mkdir -p /usr/src/nginx /usr/src/extra_module && \
    tar -zxC /usr/src/nginx -f nginx.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzC /usr/src/extra_module -f extra_module.tar.gz

WORKDIR /usr/src/nginx/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}

RUN CONFARGS=$(nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*arguments: //p') && \
    sh -c "./configure --with-compat $CONFARGS --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/extra_module/*" && make modules

FROM nginx:${VERSION}

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/nginx/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/objs/*_module.so /etc/nginx/modules/

COPY devops/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

EXPOSE 81 82
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Then, I added the module into the `nginx.conf` file. (I also tried to load the module without "")

```
load_module "modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so";
```

And finally, I wrote into http block

```
http{
    more_clear_headers      server;
    more_set_headers        "server: hidden";
    server_tokens           off;
    proxy_pass_header       server; //Tried to add it for reverse proxying, but it did not work
}
```

Only **server_tokens off;** works. I have removed nginx version, but not it's signature. **more_clear_headers** and **more_set_headers** do not affect it. What am I missing?

P.s. Checked the modules folder in the server, and my module loaded correctly

P.p.s. Tried Server with capital S, and it did not work either. (As many suggested, but my response returns it with lowercase)

[image]

Comment: [proxy_pass_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_header) does the opposite of what you're trying to do (it **Permits passing otherwise disabled header fields from a proxied server to a client.**). If it is coming from the upstream (implied) then you simply want to hide an arbitrary proxied header.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide a client request header with a Nginx reverse proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644744/hide-a-client-request-header-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy-server)

Comment: I added proxy_pass_header just to test. I put it separately and it did not work. I tried your suggestion too, but it didn't work either.

Comment: what is the upstream response? please add to the question as text, also the relevant http and server block. it may also be helpful (for you) to add another header (`add_header x-debug "a note for yourself"`) to demonstrate you are hitting the http server you think you are.

Comment: Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/214242/can-i-hide-all-server-os-info

Answer (score 0):

The server header cannot be removed unless you use Nginx Plus (paid) or build Nginx yourself and remove the header inclusion in the source code.

Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/214242/can-i-hide-all-server-os-info